# Android:Failed to load attachment error?

Tags: java, android

I am able to take a screenshot of my activity and store the file
but when i try to share it, it gives me Failed to load attachment.
I am new at android. Any help will be useful.

this is my code:

```
 public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView =  getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    Log.i("Screenshot","TAKEN");
    return bitmap;

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        Log.i("Screenshot","SAVED at"+imagePath);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void shareIt() {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    String shareBody = "My highest score is ";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My score");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    Log.i("IMAGE SHARING","TRY...");

    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("try","failed");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It is not giving me an error but when i try to share it, it gives me "failed to load attachment". Where am I going wrong?

LOG

01-20 21:10:53.689 3553-3582/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac3d5c60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

01-20 21:10:53.886 3553-3582/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40974e0

01-20 21:10:55.259 3553-3553/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy I/Screenshot: TAKEN

01-20 21:10:55.340 3553-3553/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy I/Screenshot: SAVED at/storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png

01-20 21:10:55.506 3553-3553/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy I/IMAGE SHARING: TRY...

01-20 21:10:58.858 3553-3582/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4097a90

01-20 21:11:03.767 3553-3582/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy E/EGL_emulation: tid 3582: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

01-20 21:11:03.767 3553-3582/com.quickyy.guess.com.quickyy W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac3d5c60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

Comment: Replace `image/*` with `image/jpeg`. Move `saveBitmap()` to a background thread, and add `fos.getFD().sync()` between `fos.flush()` and `fos.close()`. On Android 7.0+, once your `targetSdkVersion` reaches 24 or higher, you will no longer be able to use `Uri.fromFile()` and will need to use `FileProvider` or the equivalent instead. Also note that `ACTION_SEND` implementations do not need to support both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `Intent`.

Comment: Add a logcat so we can know more about what is happening

Comment: I assume you mean that `Log.i("try","failed");`, returned _failed_? Can you change this log line to - `Log.e("try","failed",e);`; this will dump the exception to the LogCat. Please then [edit] the question to include this output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions for media storage?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And in the code if android > 5:

```
  private static final int REQUEST_MEDIA = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
};

 int permissionMedia = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(PSImageBig.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionMedia != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PSImageBig.this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_MEDIA);
    }else{
        //code to take screenshot
    }

    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i("", "handleSignInResult onRequestPermissionsResult:" + requestCode);
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                       //code to take screenshot
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i have used permissions and also checked for the same